# Unable to connect too netezza using Aginity. IM001 Odbc driver manager error

Tags: netezza

**ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified**

OS : Windows 10 64bit
Software : Aginity Workbench For Puredata System For Analytics
Version : 4.8.0.2551

I searched a lot over internet to find the driver. But could not find. Please help me on this.

I visited https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/ . I could not know which one for windows 10 to connect to Netezza.

Please find the attached screenshot in the below link.
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhYQs.png)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that issue. Please make sure that you follow the steps below. I suspect you may not have installed the ODBC or OLEDB drivers properly.

- Read the steps carefully in this article
  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/12-easy-steps-install-ibm-netezza-software-emulator-roman-taluyev

  1. After server part let’s download and install client part (nz-winclient-v7.2.0.0.zip), again follow the link https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/reg/pick.do?source=swg-im-ibmndn&lang=en_US (choose option: IBM Netezza Client Components V7.2 for Windows 7)
  2. Unpack nz-winclient-v7.2.0.0.zip, and install “IBM Netezza Tools” (nzsetup.exe).

Run 
          Nzoledbsetup64, nzodbcsetup, nzjdbcsetup